# addChild and removeChild in flash AS3(action script3)

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild, addchild

The code that comes next is about a very very simple slide show. After clicking, i want to show a picture (or swf) and in the same time make the others disappear...
this is my code, and it works fine but in btn3, when i click, the second picture do not disappear..
I don't know why. and can you learn me some new way to rewrite my code sufficiently?

```
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;


    var my_first_swf_loading_ever:Loader=new Loader();
    my_first_swf_loading_ever.load(new URLRequest('1.jpg'));
    var my_second_pic:Loader=new Loader();
    my_second_pic.load(new URLRequest('2.jpg'));
    var my_3_pic:Loader=new Loader();
    my_3_pic.load(new URLRequest('pictures/3.jpg'));

    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);

    function clicked(evt:Event):void
    {

    if (contains(my_second_pic)) {
        removeChild(my_second_pic);
        if (contains(my_3_pic)) {
            removeChild(my_3_pic);
        }
    }
    my_first_swf_loading_ever.x=120;
    my_first_swf_loading_ever.y=120;
    addChild(my_first_swf_loading_ever);

    }


    btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked2);
    function clicked2(evt:Event):void
    {
        if (contains(my_first_swf_loading_ever)) {
            removeChild(my_first_swf_loading_ever);

            if (contains(my_3_pic)) {
                removeChild(my_3_pic);
            }
        }
        my_second_pic.x=120;
        my_second_pic.y=120;
        addChild(my_second_pic);

    }

    btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked3);
    function clicked3(evt:Event):void
    {
        if (contains(my_first_swf_loading_ever)) {
            removeChild(my_first_swf_loading_ever);
            if (contains(my_second_pic)) {
                removeChild(my_second_pic);

            }
        }
        my_3_pic.x=120;
        my_3_pic.y=120;
        addChild(my_3_pic);


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should work on formatting your code to be neater as the problem would be a lot clearer.  In the following lines:

```
if (contains(my_first_swf_loading_ever)) {
        removeChild(my_first_swf_loading_ever);
    if (contains(my_second_pic)) {
        removeChild(my_second_pic);

}}
```

The code that checks for the second picture is not executing, if you restructure the code you can see why:

```
if (contains(my_first_swf_loading_ever)) // First check
{
    removeChild(my_first_swf_loading_ever);
    if (contains(my_second_pic)) // Second check is only reached if first check returns true
    {
        removeChild(my_second_pic);
    }
}
```

Restructure as:

```
if (contains(my_first_swf_loading_ever))     // First check
{
    removeChild(my_first_swf_loading_ever);
}
if (contains(my_second_pic))                 // Second check - not reliant on first
{
    removeChild(my_second_pic);
}
```

So that both checks are carried out.  The same goes for the rest of the code, you would have the same problem on the other buttons if the checks were the other way around.

Here is a good reference you can have a look at when coding to see how different things can be formatted to help the readability of your code: http://techwiki.openstructs.org/index.php/AS3_Coding_Standards#Function_Declarations